# soft question: solution manual for Demidovich Calculus

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

**Context:** I'm taking multivariable calculus this semester and my professor takes exercises from *Problems in Mathematical Analysis* by Demidovich - a book from a few decades ago, written by russian mathematicians. The problems in this book are of much higher difficulty than, say, Thomas Calculus (probably the most used textbook for calculus courses). I'm finding the course pretty difficult and it would be useful to have a solutions manual. However, there isn't any official one, so I thought I'd ask here if anyone has worked on the book and has solutions to the problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Spanish version is circulating over there. You may try this: [https://www.academia.edu/29687679/Solucionario_demidovich_Analisis_Matematico_1_ByPriale].

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution manual, however, it is in Chinese. Also, the numbering of the problems in the Chinese solution manual is based on the original Russian problem book. That said, it might still be a useful reference to get the idea of the solutions to the problems that do not involve a lot of explaining. Moreover, sometimes the math itself can be enough to get a general idea of the solution.

The Chinese solution manual is a six-part book series (which I found [here](https://vk.com/wall-92719994_9)). A merged version of the six books can be found [here](https://mega.nz/#!nVVQiYgL!dhTzGSxQcxwDtwa0lAYAyxciSyH5SOffDTzCKoGUhK8), or on the [internet archive](https://archive.org/details/jimiduoweiqi).
As mentioned, you will have to refer to the original [Russian version](https://vk.com/wall-92719994_10) ([Alternative link](https://vk.com/doc198252603_403982546?hash=0ea88fee1792178db4&dl=307b26381c76e0a421)) of the problem book to get the corresponding problem numbers used in the solution manual.

Based on my searches, it is unlikely that there is a solution manual in English at the time of writing.

Answer (score 2):

The latest editions with couple different publishing houses and actually the textbook itself in Chinese is right here. https://archive.org/details/jimiduoweiqi

It is much higher quality (not vector pdf already, alas) and OCR'ed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is mainly Chinese versions

You can search for "吉米多维奇" on [zlibrary](https://zh.zlibrary-africa.se/) and I recommend the "吉米多维奇数学分析习题集题解1/2/3/4/5/6" series which has all problems and solutions and has very high quality.